# How can I sample from a correlated multivariate Bernoulli distribution with known covariances?

Tags: correlation, sampling, monte-carlo, joint-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

I have $N$ Bernoulli random variables $X_1, ..., X_{N}$ with known parameters $p_1, ..., p_{N}$. They are dependent with known covariances.

How can I sample from the joint distribution of the $X_i$?

I would ideally like a more general approach than [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18268/discrete-stochastic-process-exponentially-correlated-bernoulli).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This won't always work, but it may be worth a try. First compute thresholds $t_1,…,t_N$, where $\newcommand{\erfcinv}[1]{\operatorname{erfcinv}\left(#1\right)}
t_i = \sqrt{2} \erfcinv{2p_i}$, so that $\Pr(Z > t_i) = p_i$, where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable.

Then for each pair of variables $(i,j), 1 \leq i < j \leq N$, solve for the tetrachoric correlation $r_{ij}$, where $\int_0^{r_{ij}} f(t_i,t_j,\rho) \mathrm{d}\rho =$ the known covariance of variables $i$ and $j$, and $f(x,y,\rho)$ is the bivariate standard normal pdf with correlation $\rho$.
(Note: the integral, which must be evaluated numerically, is more tractable with the change of variable $\rho = \sin \theta$.)

If the matrix $R$ of tetrachoric correlations is positive definite then you're in business. Let $F$ be any matrix that gives $FF' = R$. Then for each desired binary vector $x$, generate a vector $z$ of $N$ independent standard normals, let $y = Fz$, and for $i = 1,…,N$ let $x_i = 1 if y_i > t_i$, and $x_i = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: Please check that I didn't introduce any error in your math notation (especially regarding the `\erfci` operator).

Comment: Thanks for the fixup. `\erfci(2p_i)` is the inverse complementary error function, with argument `2p_i`; the first `i` is part of the function name, signaling "inverse".

Comment: Better to leave it as is then.

Comment: `erfcinv` seems to be the common name for what I originally had as `erfci`, so I added the `nv`.

Comment: Thanks very much @RayKoopman. [This](http://www.kyb.mpg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/files/publications/attachments/macke2009_5157%5b0%5d.pdf)
 paper details a similar approach that I also found useful. It also has [Matlab code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20591-sampling-from-multivariate-correlated-binary-and-poisson-random-variables) that I haven't tried but appears useful. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @RayKoopman! Is there anything that can be done when $R$ is not positive definite? Maybe some smart regularisation or something?