# If I have a vector of $N$ correlated probabilities. How can I turn them into binary $0,1$ without destroying the correlation?

Tags: correlation, mathematical-statistics, simulation, copula

My ultimate goal is to be able to have a way to generate a vector of size $N$ of correlated Bernoulli random variables. One way I am doing this is to use the Gaussian Coupla approach. However, the Gaussian Coupla approach just leaves me with a vector:

$$
(p_1, \ldots, p_N) \in [0,1]^N
$$

Suppose that I have generated $(p_1, \ldots, p_N)$ such that the common correlation between them is $\rho$. Now, how can I transform these into a new vector of $0$ or $1$'s? In other words, I would like:

$$
(X_1, \ldots, X_N) \in \{0,1\}^N
$$

but with the same correlation $\rho$.

One approach I thought of was to assign a hard cutoff rule such that if $p_i < 0.5$, then let $X_i = 0$ and if $p_i \geq 0.5$, then let $X_i = 1$.

This seems to work well in simulations in that it retains the correlation structure but it is very arbitrary to me what cutoff value should be chosen aside from $0.5$.

Another way is to treat each $X_i$ as a Bernoulli random variable with success probability $p_i$ and sample from it. However this approach seems to cause loss of correlation and instead of $\rho$, I may get $\frac{\rho}{2}$ or $\frac{\rho}{3}$.

Does anyone have any thoughts or inputs into this? Thank you.

Comment: You have N variables. Why are you speaking of just single rho and not of a matrix of rhos?

Comment: See [this mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19406/constructing-bernoulli-random-variables-with-prescribed-correlation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand Gaussian Copula enough to know what is the problem. But I found a way to generate correlated Bernoulli vectors.

Following https://mathoverflow.net/a/19436/105908 if we take a set of fixed vectors $v_1 ... v_n$ and a random vector on the unit sphere $u$, we can transform $u$ into binary $X$ where $X_i = (u \cdot v_i > 0)$. In this setup, $cor(X_i,X_j) = \frac{\pi - 2 * \theta(i,j)}{\pi}$ where $\theta(i,j)$ is the angle between $v_i$ and $v_j$.

How to find suitable matrix $V = |v_1 ... v_n|$ to produce a desired correlation matrix $R$? The angle condition translates to $VV^T = cos(-\frac{\pi R - \pi}{2})$ and thus we can find $V$ with Cholesky decomposition.

An example code in R follows:

```
#Get a simple correlation matrix 
N = 3
cor_matrix <- matrix(c(1,0.5,0.8,0.5,1,0.4,0.8,0.4,1), N, N)

#Calculate the vectors with desired angles
vector_matrix <- chol(cos( (pi * cor_matrix - pi) * -0.5))

#You can generate random unit vectors by normalizing a vector 
#of normally distributed variables, note however that the normalization
#does not affect the sign of the dot product and so we ignore it
num_samples <- 10000
normal_rand <- matrix(rnorm(num_samples * N), num_samples, N)

#Generate the target variables
B <- (normal_rand %*% vector_matrix) > 0

#See for yourself that it works
cor(B)  
cor(B) - cor_matrix
```

Thanks @jakub-bartczuk for linking to the MO question - I wouldn't find that on my own.

---

The above code has one big limitation: the marginal distributions are fixed at $X_i \sim Bernoulli(0.5)$. I am currently unaware of how to extend this approach to fit both correlations and marginal distributions. [Another answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/65733/73129) has an approach for the general case, but it looses a lot of simplicity (it involves numerical integration). There is also paper called [Generating Spike Trains with Specified
Correlation Coefficients](http://kyb.tuebingen.mpg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/files/publications/attachments/macke2009_5157%5B0%5D.pdf) and accompanying [Matlab package](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20591-sampling-from-multivariate-correlated-binary-and-poisson-random-variables) where the sampling involves "only" finding numerically the unique zero of a monotonic function by bisection.

Comment: Thank you, this is great! Can I ask how you got that the angle condition is $VV^T = cos(-\frac{\pi R - \pi}{2})$? Thanks!

Comment: @user321627 You start with $R_{i,j} = \frac{\pi - 2 * \theta(i,j)}{\pi}$ and the relation of dot product to angle $\theta(i,j) = arccos(\frac{v_i . v_j}{|v_i|.|v_j|})$ From there it is relatively simple linear algebra I am too lazy to write down on computer :-)